# Displaying unread e-mail count with offline gmail

Tags: windows-7, email, gmail, google-gears

I am using Google Gears to use Gmail as an offline e-mail client and have the icon pinned to my (Windows 7) start bar.

I've recently seen a screenshot of someone also displaying the unread e-mails count in this icon, but I cannot remember where I saw it and how it is done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done with the free program [**Windows 7 Gmail Notifier Plus**](http://windows7center.com/news/windows-7-gmail-notifier-plus/).

[image]